# jQuery validation field by range

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I validate field by range?

I use additional-methods, but i don't know how providing parametr with range to my validation method via HTML.

Something of a
`<input type="text" class="rangeField" rel="[10, 20]" />`

It's nice, if i can make a difference between integer and decimal in validation.

Comment: Need more info, maybe an example of what the HTML looks like?

Answer (score 11):

Are you using the [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range#range) plugin?  This plugin makes it trivial to validate against a range.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [13, 23]
    }
  }
});

<input type="text" id="myrange" name="myrange" class="field" />
```